# Passing Values to Linear Regression Model in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am new to R and have built a multi linear regression model in R with three predictors now I want to pass value set for the three predictors and predict the value, below are my coefficients and intercept

(Intercept)           X              Y           Z
        -29          -0.24         3.49         8.3

I know how to write a formula and manually calculate it, but for example if i  want to pass x=0.1 Y is a factor value is '1' and Z=6 to the model and Run the model to get the output how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume your regression object's name is `mymod`. Then the `predict` function has a `newdata` argument that needs a list supplying named vectors corresponding to the RHS of your formula:

```
 predict( mymod, newdata= list(X=0.1, Y='1', Z=6) )
```

Comment: Thank you for your response